# Allow duplicates in Merge sort on singly linked list C++

Tags: c++, duplicates, mergesort, singly-linked-list

I'm getting really annoyed with this now. I am learning merge sort for univeristy and am going through this [merge sort](http://www.coders2020.com/how-do-you-sort-a-linked-list-write-a-c-program-to-sort-a-linked-list) I found on the net. However, I seem to NOT be getting duplicates and I want duplicates. Its this bit as follows but I've commented that bit out and stuff and it made the sort not work properly. Is there any way I could keep the duplicates? I'd appreciate if you could keep the answers simple. Thank you

```
else
{
    // Both are equal.
    // Arbitraritly chose to add one of them and make
    // sure you skip both!


    if(c == NULL)
    {
        c = a;
    }
    else
    {
        c->next = a;
        c = c->next;
    }

    a = a->next;
    b = b->next;
}
```

Comment: "I don't want duplicates".  "Is there any way I could keep the duplicates".  Which is it?

Comment: omg hahahaha im so tired sorry, i would like to KEEP the duplicates lol

Comment: @Tazzy: Ok.  Then could you edit your question, to make that clear?

Comment: @Oli sorry forgot to tag

Comment: @Oli ive taken the "dont" out so hopefully clearer now, will try to make clearer

Comment: @Oli and another edit there lol

Answer (score 1):

I think the clue is in the comment in the code: "*make sure you skip both*".  By incrementing *both* list pointers, you're adding one element to the output, but skipping *two* input elements.  So only increment one pointer.  Then, the other element will be moved into the output list on the next iteration.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the duplicates, then add both to the linked list `c`.  Right now you're only appending one (i.e., `a` or `b`) to the linked list.

So change your code to look like this:

```
temp_a_next = a->next;
temp_b_next = b->next;

if(c == NULL)
{
    c = a;
    c->next = b;
    c = b;
}
else
{
    c->next = a;
    c = a;
    c->next = b;
    c = b;
}

a = temp_a_next;
b = temp_b_next;
```

One more note: the final head of the sorted list with duplicates will have its starting point in `a`, since by the end of this algorithm `c` will be pointing to the end of the list, and this algorithm is actually modifying the pointers of the `a` and `b` nodes (i.e., `c` is not a new linked list with new nodes).

Answer (score 1):

You can eliminate the third case (the current else block listed in the code), and change the second case from `a > b` to `else`- it will now be handling any case where `a >= b`, and will always place `a` first in the sorted list.